# Clearing a vector of pair in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a vector 
`static std::vector<std::pair<int,std::string> > m_Data;`
and I want to clear the content before filling it with new values,
Is this a correct way to do it?

```
m_Data.clear().
```

How do you call such a vector? vector of pairs?

Comment: ... Yes ? Why wouldn't it be correct ?

Comment: Here is some reference for you: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/  When you say "what do you call the vector" are you asking for what type of vector is it?  if so then yes it is just a vector of pairs.

Comment: It's interesting that your vector is static?

Comment: static in global scope has different meaning than static local variables.

Comment: +Mehmet - static at file scope is different from static as applied to a class member and is also different from static as applied to a local variable We don't know what the scope is above, but given the name "m_Data" it's reasonable to guess that this is a class member...

Comment: a friend class was filling my vector ,dammn, I fill stupid asking. m_Data.clear(), does the job. The vector is l static local varaible so it is safe in this context. Thanks for your reply and reference!

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is. But you may clear your pair before clearing the vector. To be absolutely sure you have tools like valgrind.

> std::vector::clear
>   Clear content Removes all elements from the vector (which are
>   destroyed), leaving the container with a size of 0.

src: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/

Answer (score 0):

the answer comes late, but I had the same problem right now :D 
I've got a `std::vector< std::pair< int, std::vector< MyClass > > > complexVector`.
If I call `complexVector.clear()`, the content is not cleared, I explicitly must iterate over `complexVector` and call `complexVector[i].second.clear()` to delete the content of the inner vector. Additionally clear `first`
I am happy about suggestions for 'better' solutions :)